# How to print Mac Calendar?

Tags: mac, calendar

On macOS Monterey 12.0.1 (21A559), I use Calendar Version 11.0 (2855.1.2). How can I PRINT the calendar of the current month? There is no Print command.

Comment: Can't test Monterey [looks fine on earlier OSes up to Big Sur], but does Cmd/P work?

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you very much! Cmd/P does work. But why there is no Print button? If you write an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Where are you expecting to see a Print button? It's never had one of those, it's just always been in the File menu, same as it is on every app. Pic from Big Sur, but it's been there forever - https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4xNR.png

Comment: Thanks for your help. I expected a Print button in the left column (where the calendars are).

Comment: Apple has never done things that way. Print is a consistent global command for just about every app there is. It's always accessed by Cmd/P, or you can find it in the File menu.